# jQuery tabs not working on mobile

Tags: jquery, wordpress, mobile, plugins

I'm really breaking my head over this issue. I've developed a website local real estate agent, and everything is working properly, but one thing is driving me nuts. The jQuery tabs on the single-listing pages (like [this](http://barbel.deontwerpsmid.nl/Huizen/bussenmakerstraat-77-te-zwolle/) one) don't work on touch devices.

On desktop you can reproduce the problem in Chrome by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> (switching device mode). There is some kind of scrolling effect visible when selecting a tab, but the content matching the tab is not being shown. There are no errors in my console. I'm sure it has something to do with jQuery, but my knowledge of jQuery isn't sufficient to see the stuff that is wrong.

Any help is greatly appreciated, if I haven't provided enough info, I will update this post!

The tabs are generated by this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery( "#listing-tabs" ).tabs();
    jQuery( "#inquiry-form" ).validate();
    jQuery( ".iframe-wrap" ).fitVids();
});
```

Comment: Check your jquery UI plugin souce file, have any conflict

Comment: I can see no conflicts in the console

Comment: i) same script src be repeat two times(min.jquery), ex: 1-10.2.js  like 1-10.2-min.js so u can your view page source.

Comment: Hi Samyappa, I can see no double scripts in the source files... It looks like some kind of conflict with the plugins' js and some other js scripts... I've tried activating a different theme and disabled all other plugins, but is hasn't been helping. I really have no idea where to look next.